# Add to basket function, increase quantity rather then create new item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im having a problem with this code functionality, i want it to check through my basket array of objects, and if that id exists, to then increase the quantity attribute of that particular entry, rather then create a new object. I've tried adding in console logs to see whats being outputted, my first attempt was to create a checkBasket array, which would only have an entry in it if the basket had an already existing entry in it, this seems to work, but i cant think of how to then use that. I'm aware theres probably more better ways of handling this, but if it could be stuck to how its implemented at first, if possible, id really appreciate that. Im relatively new to react so just trying to learn from a basic place.

```js
function handleAddToBasket(event) {
    const matchedItem = list.filter((item) => item.id === event.target.value);
    const checkBasket = basket.filter((item) => item.id === event.target.value);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(checkBasket));
    if (checkBasket["id"] !== undefined) {
      console.log("im increasing the quantity");
    } else {
      const newItem = {
        ...matchedItem[0],
      };
      const newBasketItem = basket.concat(newItem);
      setBasket(newBasketItem);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(basket));
  }
```

```js
      <ul>
        {sortedList.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <span>{item.name}</span>:<span>{item.count}</span>:
            <span>{item.price}</span>
            <button type="button" value={item.id} onClick={handleAddToBasket}>
              Add to Basket
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <p>Basket Below: </p>
        {basket.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <span>{item.name} </span>

            <span>Cost: {item.price}</span>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you posted?  Is it giving errors or behaving unexpectedly?

Comment: Yeh its basically not outputting the "im increasing the quantity" and just adding another object of itself with the same id to the basket array, was hoping to check through the basket array, and then see if it matches the event.target.value. If it does it should output that to the console, which means it went into the if statement, but it seems to only execute the else part, behaving unexpectedly i guess is my response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that basket you're trying to find is present.

`basket.filter((item) => item.id === event.target.value);` will return an array of all items found.

to do a successful check you will need to get the first element of the array and then check its `id` against `undefined`

way to do that is to update your condition.

`checkBasket && checkBasket[0] && checkBasket[0]["id"] !== undefined`

another way to do this is to use `basket.find((item) => item.id === event.target.value);`
this will return first found value only and you can keep your condition as it is.

Comment: Ive tried to implement this but im now receiving an error saying checkBasket[0] os undefined

Comment: Actually managed to fix it! That solved my issue, thank you so much

Comment: yeah sorry i think i missed `&& checkBasket[0]` check. will add to answer